# selenium/webdriver: firefox/chrome browser opens but times out

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

**Problem:**

Chrome/Firefox browser opens, but doesn't navigate and times out.

**Dependencies and environment outside the default JRE libraries:**

Eclipse

Selenium Java 3.2

Browsers:

chrome - Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

firefox - 51.0.1 (32-bit)

**Firefox code:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
WebDriver netDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
netDriver.get("www.gmail.com");
```

Seems pretty straight forward, right?  But the browser doesn't get past opening, and doesn't navigate to gmail.

Stack trace:

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:293)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:267)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:263)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:122)
    at driverTest.driverTest.main(driverTest.java:13)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:20034 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
```

It looks like a proxy issue, but I'm not quite sure since I'm not familiar with Selenium that much.

**Google code:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        netDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        netDriver.navigate().to("www.gmail.com");
```

This opens the browser, but again doesn't go to gmail and times out with a different timeout error.

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:180)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:167)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
        at cucumber.feature.webStepDefinitions.navigateToWebsite(webStepDefinitions.java:23)
        at ?.Given I navigated to the QA OnBoard site(C:/Users/tscanlon/workspace/webReleaseAutomation/src/cucumber/feature/netfeature.feature:5)
      Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:18101/status] to be available after 20011 ms
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:177)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:167)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
        at cucumber.feature.webStepDefinitions.navigateToWebsite(webStepDefinitions.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
        at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:121)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
      Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:140)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
        ... 28 more
      Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:128)
        ... 29 more

    When I login                                  # webStepDefinitions.userLogin()
    Then Create a meeting                         # webStepDefinitions.meetingCreation()

Failed scenarios:


org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.1.0', revision: '86a5d70', time: '2017-02-16 07:57:44 -0800'

Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at cucumber.feature.webStepDefinitions.navigateToWebsite(webStepDefinitions.java:23)
    at ?.Given I navigated to the QA OnBoard site(C:/Users/tscanlon/workspace/webReleaseAutomation/src/cucumber/feature/netfeature.feature:5)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:18101/status] to be available after 20011 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at cucumber.feature.webStepDefinitions.navigateToWebsite(webStepDefinitions.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:121)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:128)
```

I think both are related to some kind of firewall/proxy issue.  Any advice?  I've tried several solutions with the same error every time.

Comment: Have you try another domain ? May be you can use an IP adress to be sure that it is not a problem related to a DNS request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** You need to add protocol `http` or `https` in your url e.g. https://www.gmail.com

If not working then provide  `geckodriver.exe` or `chromedriver.exe` path not firefox or chrome `exe` path

Download geckodriver [from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) or chromedriver.exe [from here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

and set property like :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drive path\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver netDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
netDriver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
```

Comment: I had used chromedriver in my debugging process earlier and this didn't seem to work, and now it's working flawlessly...any reason as to why the original chrome.exe fails consistently?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with firefox but after installation of geckodriver the problem gone so better to install geckodriver and try once